# How to dynamically set the local maven repo for a jenkins job

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to create a jenkins job using the Jenkins remote access API[1]. What I want to achieve is, I want to specify the local maven repository for the job(instead of using global repository), using the job configuration(config.xml) which I send to the create job API. How can I achieve that? What are the xml attributes that I should have added(or changed)?

[1] https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can define local maven repository for a particular job, by specifing the `localRepository` element in job configuration.
By default there are three  options supported out of the box by jenkins.

1. Default repository(~/.m2/repository)

   ```
   <localRepository class="hudson.maven.local_repo.DefaultLocalRepositoryLocator"/>
   ```
2. Local to the Executor

   ```
   <localRepository class="hudson.maven.local_repo.PerExecutorLocalRepositoryLocator"/>
   ```
3. Local to the workspace

   ```
   <localRepository class="hudson.maven.local_repo.PerJobLocalRepositoryLocator"/>
   ```

So if you want to define your own local repository locator based on build parameters or build information, you can extend the `hudson.maven.local_repo.LocalRepositoryLocator` class and implement your own logic and specify it under `localRepository`element in the job configuration.
ex:

```
<localRepository class="org.sample.MyOwnLocalRepositoryLocator"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to API its something like that:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -d @config.xml "http://JENKINS_HOST/createItem?name=Some_Job_Name"
```

Comment: Hi Stanjer,
What I want to do is, instead of using the maven repository defined in the global configuration, pass the local repository to be used for the job, with the config.xml

Comment: Ah,I see it now. Your question was not so obvious. I will try to answer it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Manually configure a job as you want it, then visit the URL `$JENKINS/job/$JOB/config.xml` — there you will be able to see which XML tags are required for your desired configuration.